# Recovering a file using WinHex

Tags: data-recovery, file-recovery

I am looking for a very small lost file which was replaced by another one having exactly the same name and size, I do not know if the original file was physically overwritten or not,it is related to OS. The target file has 970 bytes size, its type is private; it is not of the known types, and has not any of the known signatures.BUT I know some of its contents as Hex or Text Sequences.

How can I use WinHex to try recovering the original file in case it is not physically overwritten?

Comment: What makes you think its possible to recover a file replaced by new data with `WinHex`?  `WinHex` isn't file recovery software.  O suggest you restore your file from a backup.

Comment: WinHex is a DATA recovery software from x-ways 
http://www.x-ways.net/winhex/

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: OS is Win7 Ultimate

Comment: I'd start with higher level tools like recuva/photorec/easus. finding a small file on a large disk using only a hex editor sounds like looking for a needle in the state of Nebraska.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is not physically overwritten, get a hex editor, find a match of a known value in it.

You should find it in the location of the current file and into a previous location where it existed before (assuming no ovrw). Now based on the found text and the existing file, just check where it starts and where it ends, copy all that into a new file and save it. That should be your file.

I have tested this method and it works fine for small files that are not fragmented.
Judging by the file size, it cannot be fragmented, so you may be in luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that recovering a file which was replaced by another one having exactly the same name and size isn't possible. It would be like writing in the sand and then wiping that area and then replace it with new writing (text).

Winhex is an extremely powerful hexadecimal editor and can be used to recover deleted files. You can maybe try using data carving should you know the file signature of the overwritten file. All the best

Comment: I have the same fears Mr Henk Smit, but I am not sure how exactly OS performs the replacement; maybe it would write the new file in new location and change the file system pointer without overwriting the old one. Any way I have to try. Best Regards